# Issue with wordpress rich editor

Tags: wordpress

I found one issue in wordpress visiul editor, when we copy Content from ms word, like

J. williams

Editor converts it to

1. Williams,

Is anyone else facing this issue and have any solution on this,

Thanks,
Hemant

Comment: Is the "J." text or part of a numbered list that uses letters instead of numbers? WP will use HTML, but possibly won't get/copy all the markup that is hidden in MS Word, and therefore start a numbered list.

Comment: ok no, its not numbered list, its name of person, for example, if you write something like h. janh replied to my query... in ms word and just copy and paste it to Wordpress, it will change it to numbered list.

Comment: Strange. I suppose WP's editor thinks it shall be a numbered list, even though that seems silly. Try Ctrl + shift + v, that will paste as plain text, at least in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better off pasting content from Word into the `Text` tab of the visual editor instead of the `Visual` tab. This will paste just the text without all of Word's formatting, and then you can switch to the Visual tab to add your own formatting.